# Taking 400 ml mustard oil in checked in luggage to Slovenia

Tags: luggage, europe

In light of the edible mustard oil ban in EU, can I still take 400ml mustard oil in checked-in baggage? I am traveling from India.

Comment: It seems that you would use it as an edible oil which is banned in EU, maybe you should buy a mustard oil bottle which says "External use only".

Answer (score 1):

The EU legislation applies specifically to mustard oils with an erucic acid content of over 5%:

https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=LEGISSUM%3Al21121

So if you can find some mustard oil with 5% or less, you can import it legally.  This may be hard to find in India though, since mustard oil is typically ~40%, but low-acid blends are now available for sale in the UK:

https://www.harighotra.co.uk/blog/news/first-edible-mustard-oil